# -frtti has no effect to "undefined reference to typeinfo" but -fno-rtti does

Tags: c++, g++, rtti

In my code, I implements a class inherits a derived class (`class QualityOfBrightness` in `<seeta/QualityOfBrightness.h>` ) from a third library.(https://github.com/SeetaFace6Open/index)

If my code is compiled with `-frtti` or no options, it will throw error `undefined reference to "typeinfo seeta::v3::QualityOfBrightness"` when linking.

If compiled with `-fno-rtti`, it will link successfully.

So I recompiled the third library with `-frtti` so that I can use it with code compiled with `-frtti`.

But it has no effect.I still need to add `-fno-rtti` so that my code can compile. I used to see the `CMakeOutput.log` and it does be compiled with `-frtti`.

If `-fno-rtti` added, I need to recompile opencv with it and I won't be able to use `typeid`, `dynamic_cast`etc.

I don't know what to do next. I'm sure all functions have been defined. Is there any other posibility causing this?

My compiler is gcc10.2, my OS is debian 11 (bullseye).

Below is an example:

```cpp
#include <seeta/QualityOfBrightness.h>

using namespace seeta;

class Handler: public QualityOfBrightness {
public:

    Handler() : QualityOfBrightness() {};
    ~Handler()  {};
    QualityResult
    check (
        const SeetaImageData &image,
        const SeetaRect &face,
        const SeetaPointF *points,
        const int32_t N) override {
        return QualityResult (QualityLevel::HIGH);
    };
};

int
main (void)
{
    Handler a;
}
```

The class QualityOfBrightness and its base class QualityRule are from a third library .(If you need to see more, see https://github.com/SeetaFace6Open/index)

```cpp
class QualityOfBrightness : public QualityRule {
public:
    using self = QualityOfBrightness;
    using supper = QualityRule;
    
    SEETA_API QualityOfBrightness();

    SEETA_API QualityOfBrightness (float v0, float v1, float v2, float v3);
    
    SEETA_API ~QualityOfBrightness() override;
    
    SEETA_API QualityResult check (
        const SeetaImageData &image,
        const SeetaRect &face,
        const SeetaPointF *points,
        const int32_t N) override;
        
private:
    QualityOfBrightness (const QualityOfBrightness &) = delete;
    QualityOfBrightness &operator= (const QualityOfBrightness &) = delete;
    
private:
    void *m_data;
};
class QualityRule {
public:
    using self = QualityRule;
    
    virtual ~QualityRule() = default;
    
    virtual QualityResult check (
        const SeetaImageData &image,
        const SeetaRect &face,
        const SeetaPointF *points,
        int32_t N) = 0;
};
```

Comment: We need a [mcve]. I can only guess that you declared some virtual function or an extern variable that is not defined and not used.

Comment: I will add one example.

Comment: You don't seem to link SeetaFace6Open to your app.

Comment: no, I have linked it. if set compile option  "-fno-rtti" it can work

Comment: @273K Oh.I find the third library is compiled with another option `-fvisibility=hidden`. If I remove it, then my code can compile withoud `-fno-rtti`. So ,I think, the bug results from this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.I find the third library is compiled with another option `-fvisibility=hidden`. If I remove it, then my code can compile withoud `-fno-rtti`. So ,I think, the bug results from this option.